# IOS Simulator Location Access Problem - Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

```
Future<String> getCurrentLocation() async {
    late Placemark place;
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);

      latitude = position.latitude;
      longitude = position.longitude;

      print("Geolocator worked");

      List<Placemark> placemarks =
          await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
      place = placemarks[0];
      print("Location to city worked");
      print("Place: ${place.locality}");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return place.locality.toString();
  }
```

Here is my code to get current location and the city name of the current lat-log. However, when I started the code, I can't see any permission screen on my simulator. Simulator version is iOS 15.2.

And here is the error code from try-catch block:

```
flutter: User denied permissions to access the device's location.
```

However, like I said no permission access screen shows up on my simulator.

Also:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
```

I already added these to Info.plist.

Comment: At least in native iOS development you need to request the location permission, it does not automatically ask on first use. I would assume Flutter provides a way to do that.

Comment: @Arkku I don't know how it works tbh. this is the first time I'm trying to access geolocation. However,in the geolocator package documents, these are enough to access location.

Answer (score 0):

Add [permission_handler package](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) to your `pubspec.yaml`, and ask for permission before trying to use `Geolocator`. There are different possibilities, check the following code:

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future<bool> isLocationAvailable() async {
  // get current permission status of location
  var permissionStatus = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;

  // if restricted, it can't be used
  if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.restricted) {
    return Future.value(false);
  }

  // it can be switched off, so it can't be used
  if (!await Permission.locationWhenInUse.serviceStatus.isEnabled) {
    return Future.value(false);
  }

  // if user permanently denied access, it can't be used
  if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
    return Future.value(false);
  }

  // get permission and return result
  return await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request().isGranted;
}
```

And call this before you try to get location:

```
if (await isLocationAvailable()) {
  // get location here
}
```